# Determine which SQL data types require value to be quoted?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to send a command to a database.  I know the names and data types of all the fields in the affected table, and I need to generate a command using them.  My only problem is determining which column values are of data types that require quotes in TSQL - for example, if the field was a string `Hello World` of type `varchar`, I'd need to quote it, but if it were an `int`, 5, I wouldn't need to quote it.

I could use something like the following code, but it seems very inefficient.  Can someone point me to a better way of doing this - possibly using a built in SQL server or C# feature?

```
public string QuoteStringIfDatatypeRequires(string columnName)
{
    if (DataTypes[columnName].Contains("date") || DataTypes[columnName].Contains("time") ||
        DataTypes[columnName].Contains("char") || DataTypes[columnName].Contains("text") ||
        DataTypes[columnName].Contains("binary") || DataTypes[columnName].Contains("image"))
    {
        return "'" + columnName + "'";
    }

    return columnName;
}
```

Comment: This is just a SQL injection accident waiting to happen. Have you thought about using **[parameterized queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)** instead?

Comment: What represent `columnName`? A value you want to insert in your tables or the name of a column? Really I do not understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I looked into parameterized queries and it'll work.  I'm not familiar with C# so I didn't really know what I was asking for.  I'll accept that answer when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can quote everything, and that will be converted to the appropriate data type by database itself.

But that will be incorrect. Instead you need to use parameterized queries and send values as is:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
```

or

```
command.Parameters.Add("@name", type, size).Value = value;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> You can quote everything, and that will be converted to the
>   appropriate data type by database itself.

I wanted to point out that this is not necessarily true (reference Binary and BigInt types). You will get exceptions converting VARCHAR to certain value types.  I was only able to get around these exceptions using the following approach:

```
public string RenderField(string fieldValue, string fieldType)
{
    // Null check
    if (fieldValue == null || fieldValue.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        // Not there
        return null;
    }

    // Switch on type
    switch (fieldType)
    {
        // Cases
        case "TimeSpan":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "String":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "Char[]":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "DateTime":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "DateTimeOffset":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "Guid":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "Boolean":
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
        case "Int64":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Byte[]":
            return fieldValue;            
        case "Decimal":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Double":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Int32":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Single":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Int16":
            return fieldValue;
        case "Byte":
            return fieldValue;
        default:
            ToolOperations.Log("WARNING => UNSUPPORTED SQL TYPE: " + fieldType, false);
            return ToolOperations.QuotedValue(fieldValue);
    }
}
```